# Being above 10,000 rep, my newest edit was placed in a review queue as if I was a low-rep user?

Tags: support, bug, login

I made a minor edit to:

[log difference measure](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51005/log-difference-measure)

and was informed that the edit was put in a review queue. In fact, it was, and I can even decide on my own edit:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/5W6lQAn.png]

Note that I'm displayed as "anonymous user", and I was logged in all the time.

This has happened to me before, but it's been a year or two.

A couple of times per week (i.e. sporadically, in midst of having been active on Stack Exchange sites), I also get informed that "user doesn't have permission to comment on this post" when trying to comment on a question. (I can "recover" from that by copying the comment to clipboard, reloading the page, and posting it); here's a screenshot from electronics.stackexchange.com:

[image]

Is there something strange with my account?

In all these situations, the black banner on top of the page clearly indicated SE still "knew who I am" and was logged in.

System data:

- Firefox 59.0.2 64b

  - Suspicious plugins:

    - Greasemonkey (disabled on *.stackexchange.com)
    - Privacy badger (allowing all but *scorecardresearch.com), also doesn't explain sporadicity
    - uBlock (same allowance / deny rules as Privacy badger above)
  - No observable difference in session cookies
- Linux x86_64
- NAT with as-good-as-persistent cable connection (connection uptime with same external IPv4 address 13 days something)

*EDIT*: The "not allowed to comment" problem has occurred nearly daily on different machines by now.

Comment: I can only imagine this happens when your cookies in your browser are somehow being invalidated or removed by an upstream network-device. In that light it might help if you can share which browser you use, list any plugins that are running, Operating System, Virus scanner, Network equipment you know of, type of network/ISP (mobile or not).

Comment: @rene added to the question. Also, SE is HTTPS-only pretty much. I don't see how anything could remove any data from the stream without raising *a lot* of alarm bells on my end.

Comment: How do you normally recover from that half-logged-in state?

Comment: reload the page, @rene. (copy comment to clipboard first)

Comment: That is really strange. I still suspect it is something on your end but maybe a dev spots something in the logs.

Comment: I had this happen to me once, and as soon as I refreshed the page, I saw that SE thought I _wasn't_ logged in. I just assumed that the cookie wasn't good _forever_, and logged in again. Now, before I do an edit, I just refresh the page to make sure that I'm still logged in, rather than reading my "logged in" page from cache.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin nope, I'm not getting logged out.  And the edit I made was about 30s after loading that page. Not sure how much fresher you can get :)

Comment: By the way, still happens on a daily basis.

Comment: Happens multiple times per day now.